# Convert From String To date with 12 hours time formatting

Tags: swift, date-formatting

Since yesterday I'm trying to solve this issue but I give up. Now I have string date `"2018-10-30 01:00 PM"` and when I'm trying to convert it to date the time format will change to 24 hours. I mean it will be like `"2018-10-30 13:00:00 UTC"`.

Here is my code:

```
let dateFormatter5 = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter5.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
dateFormatter5.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

dateFormatter5.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")! as TimeZone

let now = dateFormatter5.date(from: "2018-10-30 01:00 pm")!
```

I need to convert this string with the same time format (12 hours). 
Any idea?

Comment:  Sorry, but this gets asked way more then it should.  A date/time class is nothing more then a container for the amount of time which has passed since a specific point in time (typically the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch).  They don't carry a concept of format, this is why you have date/time formatters.  What you are seeing is the developers been nice and providing a `toString` implementation which provides a human readable representation of the object

Comment: Your code is fine (other than the use of `NSTimeZone`). There is nothing to fix or do. But, when it comes to showing `now` to the user, you will need to convert it to a string using `DateFormatter`.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but your timezone code should be: `dateFormatter5.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`. Don't needlessly use `NSTimeZone`.

Comment: Why do you want `date` object to be in 12 hours format?

Comment: i have reminder needed to be added to user, and i need to remove the period from 12:00 am to 6:00 am and this string i already take it from user

Comment: To set reminder, you got the date from the `string` so just use this date. If you need to get back the same `string` again then you can use `dateFormatter.string(from: date)`. Its still unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If your original date string is UTC timezone:

```
let dateStr = "2018-10-30 01:00 PM"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
if let now = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr) {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'"
    dateFormatter.string(from: now)  // "2018-10-30 13:00:00 UTC"
}
```